# Understanding recur

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

Trying out this snippet of code and doesn't seem to be working quite right..

```
(defn- multiple_of?
  [div num]
  (= (mod num div) 0))

(defn sum_of_multiples_from 
  ([start] (sum_of_multiples_from start 0))
  ([start total]
   (if (<= start 0)
     total
     (recur (dec start) (or (multiple_of? 3 start) (multiple_of? 5 start)
                            (+ total start) start)))))
```

I receive the following error:

> java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

I am guessing it has to do with:

```
(recur (dec start) (or (multiple_of? 3 start) (multiple_of? 5 start)
                            (+ total start)
                            start)))))
```

But I'm not sure why, I'm new to clojure, so I'm trying to get a grasp of recur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `or` call returns a boolean (`(multiple_of? 3 start)`) as soon as start is a multiple of 3.

In Clojure, `or` always *returns one of its arguments* -- either the first truish one if one exists, or the last falsish one otherwise.

Comment: Would the _clojure_ way be to wrap that in an if? Something like `(if (or multiple_of? 3 start) (multiple_of? 5 start)) (+ total start) start)` or am I way off ?

Comment: `(if (or multiple_of? 3 start) ...)` will test the function `multiple_of?` without calling it. You need parens to make calls. `(if (or (multiple_of? 3 start) (multiple_of? 5 start)) ...)`

Answer (score 4):

You really want a conditional expression for your `recur`, and one that always returns a number. For example:

```
(defn sum_of_multiples_from
  ([start] (sum_of_multiples_from start 0))
  ([start total]
    (if (<= start 0)
      total
      (recur (dec start)
         (if  (or (multiple_of? 3 start) (multiple_of? 5 start))
           (+ total start)
           total)))))
```

Note that this is a weird way to implement this in a functional language. You're really picking values from a range and adding them up, so it's better to implement this as a filter and a reduce, for example:

```
(reduce + (filter #(or (multiple_of? 3 %) (multiple_of? 5 %)) (range 50)))
=> 543
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your refined solution. Instead of reduce, I used apply.